# Whether we use users or user?

Tags: writing, technical

I am wondering whether we use "user" or "users" in a technical document; specifically a user guide or specification document in those sentences like " with this feature user can issue . ...." or " this feature helps user ...."?
My work is checking and editing technical documents, it feels like both of them are correct but which one is standard?

Answer (score 4):

Both examples are wrong.  It should be "with this feature, the user can" or "with this feature, users can"  or "this feature helps the user" or "this feature helps users"   I recommend using "users".

Answer (score 1):

I often see "users" being prefered over "user" just to prevent having to use "he/she" as the plural requires the gender independent "they".

"Users can use the radio button should they wish to..."

"The user can use the radio button should he/she wish to..."

Comment: Not so. "The user can use the radio button should they wish to" is available.

Comment: @edmin-ashworth, can you explain a bit more why you can use "they" for a singular "user"?

Comment: Yes, but why don't you look up 'singular they' yourself in a search here and/or on Google. [Suggestion, so I'm not including a '?'] Is 'edmin' a portmanteau?